# Anybody knows how to use Zend_db component with oci8 in Zend framework?

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

I am going to use Zend framework to access data from an oracle database. Previously I have the class I built to interact with the database (outside of framework), those are all procedural and function calls in the database (not SELECT statements), I have to bind variables and then execute them. I am looking to use Zend_db component to access oci8 adapter. Anyone knows how to do that or can point me to a tutorial, that will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: There are none what I can find of, however, I wrote my own OCI8 adapter, you can write your own too in Zend/Auth/Adapter location with the class declaration of `class Zend_Auth_Adapter_OCI8Login implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface` feel free to give your class any name you want.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search yielded [this PDF](http://static.zend.com/topics/oracle_and_php.pdf) and [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/11gr2_db_prod/appdev/opensrclang/php/php.htm) from Oracle. The Oracle tutorial shows how to bind variables and execute stored procedures. Perhaps those have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $dbAdapterConfig = array(
        'driver' => 'Oci8',
        'connection_string' => '192.168.0.70/pep',
        'username' => 'xx',
        'password' => 'xx',
        'character_set' => 'AL32UTF8',
        'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false)
    );

    $adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($dbAdapterConfig);
    $result = $adapter->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT FROM B2B_INFO_SHOP', Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

    if ($result)
        echo $result->current()->CNT, "\n";

    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = $sql->select()
        ->from('B2B_INFO_SHOP');
    $select->where(array('SHOPID' => 123));
    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
    echo $selectString, "\n";

     $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    if ($result)
      echo $result->current()["SHOPNAME"];
```